# Delete Dynamic Memory

Tags: c++, list, hashtable, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I have a HashTable templated class and I'm having trouble deleting a dynamic array. (SLList = Singly Linked List)

My data members are:

```
SLList<Type>* m_ht;
unsigned int(*m_hFunction) (const Type &v);
unsigned int m_numOfBuckets;
```

In my constructor/assignment operator, I have the 'new' allocating the dynamic memory:

```
m_ht = new SLList<Type>[numOfBuckets];
```

My destructor:

```
m_ht = nullptr;
for (size_t i = 0; i < m_numOfBuckets; ++i) // idk if this for loop
    delete m_ht[i];                         // is correct
delete[] m_ht;
```

After closing the program and tracking the memory leaks, they are pointing for these both *'m_ht = new ...'*, and I don't know how to delete them properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should move `m_ht = nullptr;` to the last line. Otherwise, the following `delete` and `delete[]` cannot get the address to release.